# How to count the runtime of an algorithm with an expanding array (which itself is looped) inside a loop?

Tags: time-complexity

I have an algorithm for finding a **list of primes** under N, and also the **lowest factor** of all the numbers N.

```
/*
arrLF stands for arrLowestFactor, it stores all the LF
arrPrime is the list of primes under N. The variable pn is used to keep track of how many primes we have discovered. Initially pn is zero.
*/
for(int i = 2; i <= N; i++){
     //if a number i hasn't got its lowest factor yet, it means we have discovered a new prime number. And this prime number will be the LF of i too.
    if(!arrLF[i]){
        arrPrime[pn++] = i;
        arrLF[i] = i;
    } 

    //run through the list of prime once and fill up the lowest factor of (i * arrPrime[j]) in the arrLF table 
    //it's like doing sieve of eratosthenes but we build the table up one at a time
    for(int j = 1; i * arrPrime[j] <= N; j++){
        arrLF[ i * arrPrime[j] ] = arrPrime[j];
        if( i % arrPrime[j] == 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

For the outer loop, it's running at O(N). So the running of this algorithm will be O(N * M), where M is the runtime of the inner loop. But since the list of primes is expanding unconsistently, how do I assess complexity of M?

Btw I found this algorithm by studying a solution of a red coder on codeforce, does anyone know this algorithm or its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your algorithm will run in O(n) . Let me explain why

we need to look at the inner loop to understand why it does not affect time complexity in exponential manner .

the inner loop look will run in worst case the following number of time for each iteration

1st iteration : 1/2 * N times

2nd iteration : 1/3 * N times

3rd iteration : 1/4 * N times

and so on

So the number of times the inner loop is running is decreasing each time we do it .

and we can say the total number of times the inner loop will run is 
SUM(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... 1/N)

and this is called harmonic series 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

and although this series converge to infinity, it converge very slowly that for N of 10^43 it is  less than 100

so realistically the inner loop will run in worst case constant number of N times lets say 100 times max for java float limit

So that mean the time complexity of the full algorithm is the time complexity of the inner loop because the outer loop does not run any other loops .
So the time complexity will be O(Xn) where X is constant number that as we explained will realistically not exceed 100 or 200 within the numbers limits of java which will mean the total complexity of the algorithm is O(n) since we omit the constant

Comment: OMG this is so GOOD!! I can fully understand your answer and it has also increased my understanding of worst case and iteration counting. 
Really thanks a lot!